# Convergence in Law implies a.s. convergence (Donsker-like statement)

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, weak-convergence, central-limit-theorem

I am currently working on a Donsker-like convergence result and I am not quite sure, whether my conclusions are correct (I am dropping the technicalities here):

Let $\hat{N}_n(t)$ be a an estimator for $N(t)$, we then have
$$
\sqrt n(\hat{N}_n(t)-N(t))\overset{\mathcal L} \longrightarrow \mathbb G  \text{ in } \ell^\infty (\mathbb R)
$$
where $\mathbb G $ denotes some Gaussian random variabel (with known covariance structure) and $\ell^\infty$ is the space of bounded real-valued functions (**why actually not only continuous-bounded as usual?**) equipped with the sup-norm. Convergence in *Law* for $X_n\overset{\mathcal L}\longrightarrow X$ means here in this setting
$$
\forall f\in \ell^\infty:\lim_{n\to\infty}Ef(X_n)=Ef(X)
$$
which means we have actually 
$$
\forall f\in \ell^\infty:\lim_{n\to\infty}Ef\left(\sqrt n(\hat{N}_n(t)-N(t))\right)=Ef\left(\mathbb G \right)
$$ 
I was wondering, in a setting like this, can we conclude 
$$
\hat{N}_n(t)\to N(t)\text{ a.s.?}
$$
Here is my thinking:

We have
$$
\forall f\in \ell^\infty:\lim_{n\to\infty}Ef\left(\sqrt n(\hat{N}_n(t)-N(t))\right)=Ef\left(\mathbb G \right)
$$
which means that the convergence also holds for the continuous bounded-functions and then by the Portmanteau theorem we have convergence of the distribution functions in all continuous points $c$, we have
$$
\forall c:\lim_{n\to\infty}P\{\left(\sqrt n(\hat{N}_n(t)-N(t))\right)\leq c\}=P\{\mathbb G \leq c\}
$$

Now we are interested in $(\hat{N}_n(t)-N(t))$, so
$$
\forall c:\lim_{n\to\infty}P\{\left(\hat{N}_n(t)-N(t))\right)\leq c\}=\lim_{n\to\infty} P\{\left( \sqrt n(\hat{N}_n(t)-N(t))\right) \leq \sqrt n c\}
$$
which is for $c>0$ equal to $1$ and for $c<0$ equal to $0$. For $c=0$ we don't have a continuous point of $F$. So we have the distribution function of random variable a.s. equal to $0$ (Dirac distribution).

Since $(\hat{N}_n(t)-N(t))\to 0 $ in distribution we have even $(\hat{N}_n(t)-N(t)) \overset{\text{a.s.}} \longrightarrow 0 $.

**EDIT**: As pointed out by Did in the comments, the convergence  of
$(\hat{N}_n(t)-N(t)) \longrightarrow 0$ is actually in probability. The implication is: Convergence in distribution against a constant implies convergence against this constant in probability.

Is this reasonable or have I overseen anything?

Comment: What you show is that $Z_n\to0$ in distribution, for some given sequence $(Z_n)$. This cannot imply that $Z_n\to0$ almost surely but this does imply that $Z_n\to0$ in probability because $0$ is a constant (and if you knew that $Z_n\to Z$ almost surely, for any random variable $Z$, then you could deduce that $Z_n\to Z$ in distribution).

Comment: Ah, sure. I messed up the implication, I somehow thought that convergence in distribution against a constant would imply almost sure convergence. Thanks for the correction!

Comment: So, no question left?

Comment: @Did at this point I'd say that my confusion has been resolved. I found it strange that in every source I checked the above implication was never mentioned. I've checked Van der Vaart and Dudley for Donsker (like) theorems but neither actually discussed the result. I guess I just needed some intuition which I now have, thanks again!